# Launch Outlook to compose a message with subject and attachment by Outlook's command line switches

Tags: outlook, command

The following Outlook's command works well with Outlook 2010:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "&subject=abc" /a "c:\attach.txt"
```

But it does not work with Outlook 2007 and 2003. The strange are following commands work well with Outlook 2007 and 2003:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "&subject=abc"
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /a "c:\attach.txt"
```

How do I use one command line switch to launch Outlook to compose message with both subject and attachment for Outlook 2010/2007/2003?

Comment: It could be a security feature. You can't use any other means, such as another application?

Comment: Welcome @Nam, I notice that this is your first post here on Stack Overflow. This question does not seem to me very related to programming. Maybe you can get more attention by posting it to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/about)

Answer (score 10):

So far from what I've discovered with Outlook 2007 is that in order to achieve this you have to realize that `/a` implies `/c IPM.note`.

So using

```
outlook.exe /a "FileName" /m "addresses&cc=&subject=&body="
```

Works just fine (took me forever to figure this out cause everyone on the web appears to insist that you must use `/c` when doing `/m` but not taking into account that `/a` does this for you automatically.

Also, I've noticed that using `%20` isn't exactly correct when needing to put spaces, instead `%2` (`%20` without the `0`) is doing the trick there. Otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of `0`'s after all the spaces, very strange indeed.

Comment: @pault claims that this, or the other solution, also works in Outlook 2003 if you have SP3 and Outlook 2003 [update 2449798](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2449798).  He made this comment in an answer that was since deleted (as it was not an answer), I am writing this to preserve the knowledge.

Comment: With `%2` instead of `%20` i get `?` means: `Hello%2World` becomes `Hello?orld` (NOTE the missing `W`). `%20` works like expected (using Outlook 2013).

Comment: In Microsoft Outlook 365, the addresses seem to be separated from subject body with ? not &.   Like  /m "addresses?subject=&body="   See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Outlook

Comment: Prior to outlook.exe 16 (Outlook 365) all parameters in the argument of /m were separated by &. In the newer version, after the email address we need to use ? and then all other parameters need to be separated by &. I've tested it

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add this here.

Every time I get a new PC, I have to configure my Task Scheduler to launch my daily email to management. Every time I search, I come across this one, but it isn't quite what I want.

I want a daily email to be sent to a group entitled "DailyLog" with the Subject="Daily Log" (I didn't say I was being original).

I start with this KB from Microsoft:

[How to use command line switches to create a pre-addressed e-mail message in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287573)

Here are the screenshots for that, but the only one you really need to pay attention to is the **Action** tab:

[image: General]

[image: Triggers]

[image: Actions]

In the image above, the Actions tab is where all of the important information goes.

Depending on your version of Microsoft Outlook, your path could look different.

[image: Edit Action]

Notice the **Program/script** section needs to be in quotes. The **Add arguments (optional)** is *NOT* in quotes!

Here is what I use in the arguments text box:

> /c ipm.note /m DailyLogGroup;&subject=Daily%20Log

The `/c` switch creates the message (ipm.note), and the `/m` switch places the group `DailyLogGroup` in the **TO** field with the text `Daily Log` in the subject (`%20` is a blank space).

[image: Conditions]

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1):

```
Outlook > Tools > Forms > DesignForm > Message > Open

    To = "abc@xyz.com"

ViewCode

    Function Item_Open()
    If Item.Size = 0 Then : Item.Send : End If
    End Function

File > Close > Publish > PublishFormAs

    DisplayName = "test_130713_0856"

Publish > [CLOSE] > Yes

send_email.bat
--------------
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" ^
    /c "IPM.Note.test_130713_0856" ^
    /m "abc@xyz.com&subject=hello world&body=blah blah blah" ^
    /a h:\test.txt
```

Comment: @pault claims that this, or the other solution, also works in Outlook 2003 if you have SP3 and Outlook 2003 [update 2449798](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2449798).  He made this comment in an answer that was since deleted (as it was not an answer), I am writing this to preserve the knowledge.