# Launch outlook 2013 from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-2013

How can I close and open outlook 2013 programmatically using C# ?

Here is the problem that I am trying to solve.
I have set up an automatic backup of my .pst files to a external hard drive. I am using the free software 'SyncBackFree' for the backup. The issue is the back up fails because the .pst file is open in outlook. 
I am thinking of developing a windows service that will shut down outlook at a fixed time and after 20 minutes or so, will launch the outlook again. 
I could not find any documentation to shut down and launch outlook. 
I tried looking at [Launch Outlook to compose a message with subject and attachment by Outlook's command line switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912973/launch-outlook-to-compose-a-message-with-subject-and-attachment-by-outlooks-com)

Please advise.

Comment: What have you tried ? Show your code ? Did you think about killing process and starting process ?

Comment: @Xaruth...Thanks for the suggestion about killing process. I will try that. My problem was, I had no idea where to start.

Comment: `taskkill /F /IM outlook.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to kill process and launch it later.

Something like this :

**kill**

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook.exe"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

**launch** (don't forget to set `pathOutlook`)

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(pathOutlook, "outlook.exe");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = pathOutlook ;
Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks Xaruth....I accepted your answer. Stackoverflow does not allow me to upvote your answer.